# How to remove quotes for json keys in json string using regex in jq

Tags: json, regex, jq

Trying to convert json payload to graphql and having some troubles.
I need to convert string like

```
"{
  \"entity\":{
    \"id\":\"7fbe7e65-0f01-4934-a2a9-dcc6d81a5b95\",
    \"type\":\"Products\",
    \"status\":\"pending\",
    \"services\":[
      {
        \"id\":\"1e05737e-754b-4d19-b872-5a0135d99cf4\",
        \"type\":\"Services\",
        \"status\":\"active\"
      },{
        \"id\":\"2238fe75-3d1a-4768-8464-be7d48037215\",
        \"type\":\"Services\",
        \"status\":\"active\"
      }
    ]
  }
}"
```

to string where no quotes for keys:

```
"{
  entity:{
    id:\"7fbe7e65-0f01-4934-a2a9-dcc6d81a5b95\",
    type:\"Products\",
    status:\"pending\",
    services:[
      {
        id:\"1e05737e-754b-4d19-b872-5a0135d99cf4\",
        type:\"Services\",
        status:\"active\"
      },{
        id:\"2238fe75-3d1a-4768-8464-be7d48037215\",
        type:\"Services\",
        status:\"active\"
      }
    ]
  }
}"
```

I managed to replace only all quotes but how can I remove quotes only for keys?
Please note that I have added \n here just for better understanding. Normally I got the json as a string without \n.

Comment: try 
cat your.file.json | tr -d '\n' | jq '.' --raw-output

Comment: Thanks but it returns json and keys are quoted.

Comment: Why not simply `JSON.parse()` and then format your new string as needed?

Comment: This will do the trick: `<your.json sed -E 's/\\":/:/; s/^( +)\\"/\1/'`, but idiomatically it's incorrect - should be done as @Justinas mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The illustrative input is some form of escaped JSON, so it would probably make sense to begin by unescaping it.  Using your example, I'll show how this can be done in three ways, but deciding which method will be appropriate will depend on how the escaped JSON was generated.

I'll then suggest some additional transformations which may be useful on the road to graphQL.

For clarity, I've copied the escaped JSON into a file, escaped.json:

```
$ cat escaped.json
"{
  \"entity\":{
    \"id\":\"7fbe7e65-0f01-4934-a2a9-dcc6d81a5b95\",
    \"type\":\"Products\",
    \"status\":\"pending\",
    \"services\":[
      {
        \"id\":\"1e05737e-754b-4d19-b872-5a0135d99cf4\",
        \"type\":\"Services\",
        \"status\":\"active\"
      },{
        \"id\":\"2238fe75-3d1a-4768-8464-be7d48037215\",
        \"type\":\"Services\",
        \"status\":\"active\"
      }
    ]
  }
}"
```

#### Using jq to "unescape" the escaped JSON

One possibility would be to use jq's `fromjson`:

```
jq fromjson <<< $(cat escaped.json)
```

or

```
tr -d '\n' < escaped.json | jq fromjson
```

For brevity, consider instead:

```
    $ jq 'fromjson|length' <<< $(cat escaped.json)
    1
```

#### Using `eval` to "unescape" the escaped JSON

In the following, I'll assume a bash or bash-like shell, but the same kind of thing can be done in other shells.

To show that `eval` produces valid JSON, I've piped the result into `jq length`:

```
$ eval echo $(cat escaped.json) | jq length
1
```

#### Escaped JSON in a variable

If the shell variable, $x, contains the escaped JSON, we can similarly use `eval`.  Consider, for example:

```
$ jq length <<< $x
287
$ jq length <<< $(eval printf $x)
1
```

### On the road to graphQL

Using the original escaped JSON, the following combination of jq and sed produces the result shown below.

```
jq 'fromjson 
    | walk(if type == "array" or type == "object" then . else null end)' <<< $(cat escaped.json) |
  sed '/"/{s/"//g; s/: null.*//;}'
```

#### Output

```
{
  entity: {
    id
    type
    status
    services: [
      {
        id
        type
        status
      },
      {
        id
        type
        status
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the quotation marks around the keys, the following may suffice.

```
tr -d '\n' < escaped.json |
  jq fromjson |
  sed '/^ *".*": /{s/"//; s/": /: /;}'
```

With the sample input, this produces:

```
{
  entity: {
    id: "7fbe7e65-0f01-4934-a2a9-dcc6d81a5b95",
    type: "Products",
    status: "pending",
    services: [
      {
        id: "1e05737e-754b-4d19-b872-5a0135d99cf4",
        type: "Services",
        status: "active"
      },
      {
        id: "2238fe75-3d1a-4768-8464-be7d48037215",
        type: "Services",
        status: "active"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```